# How can i refactor this to remove DRY

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two serializers implemented here with same methods that is to validate the files 1 and 2 how can i refactor my code here so that i take care of DRY

**serializers.py**

```
class FilecreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'file',
           
        )

    def create(self, data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.is_anonymous:
            validated_data.update({'uploaded_by': user.person})
        return super().create(data)

    def file_checking(self, file):
        ca = pd.read_excel(file, dtype=str)
        if not something():
            raise ValidationError()
        return file


class FileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ('file_2',)

    def file_2_checking(self, file):
        ca = pd.read_excel(file, dtype=str)
        if not something():
            raise ValidationError()
        return file
```

Comment: if `FileCreateSerializer` and `FileUpdateSerializer ` both, use the same model, fields and validation are the same, just write one serializer with `create`, `update` and also a `validate`. [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate mixin class with the common function and inherit in both serializer.